# NunitForms not loading .dll from Project

Tags: nunit, badimageformatexception

when I'm trying to load my class file : classLibrary1.dll in the recorder, I'm getting the following error message.
My project has been built on .NET framework 4.5. Just cant seem to find the solution to it.
This is the message I'm getting :

**System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\anirban.m1\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.**

Answer (score 0):

It says that the NUnitForms does not work with .NET 4.5.

I think NUnit Forms supports only up to .NET 3.5.

Update:
Maybe there is a mismatch between x86 and x64?

Comment: but I changed the framework of my project to 2 n 3 also but that didn't work either

Comment: the target is set to any CPU

Comment: Maybe you are using a reference which is built for another target?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error with a project i was working on. Try running it with a platform target set to 'Any CPU'.

Project settings -> Build -> Platform target: